# when using Handler

Tags: android, handler, using

Hi everybady I try to use Handler but I have sum problem 
1. when I use Handler

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void close() {

            }

            @Override
            public void flush() {

            }

            @Override
            public void publish(LogRecord record) {

            }
        };
```

but ı want this type

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable3sec,3000);
```

how to resolve my problemn
 thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the import you use, change your import like import `android.os.Handler`

Comment: package com.softengine.mehmet.example2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import android.os.Handler.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.concurrent.Delayed;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord; i import all but ide wants override all handler methods

Answer (score 2):

Just change `Handler` class `import` from:

```
java.util.logging.Handler
```

to

```
android.os.Handler
```

Comment: @MehmetOnar: see at top of class file you have `java.util.logging.Handler` line change it to `android.os.Handler`. if you are unable to locate then use IDE find and replace option to replace  `java.util.logging.Handler` with `android.os.Handler`

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.softengine.mehmet.example2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.concurrent.Delayed;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        final Runnable runnable3sec = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                nextActivity();
            }
        };
        Handler myHandler = new Handler();
        myHandler.postDelayed(runnable3sec,3000);


    }

    public void nextActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

thank you everybady :)